# A nice selector to remove this horrible code

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

can anyone offer a selector to do away with this horrible chunk of code:

```
// img is the image element...
var descriptionContent = $(".descriptionContent", img.parent("td").parent("tr").next("tr"));
```

The html looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="descriptionContent" /></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Repeat n times -->
</table>
```

Given a user has clicked on the img, I need to get the next (and only the next) `.descriptionContent` element.

Thanks,
K

Comment: Your current selector doesn't look that horrible to me.

Comment: Really? But if I change the structure to wrap the image in something later, I'll have to redo the code? Wouldn't it be better to have something that'll select the parent '*properly*'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're worried about wrapping the image in something, Try this:

```
var descriptionContent = $(".descriptionContent", img.closest("tr").next("tr"));
```

The closest command finds the nearest ancestor matching the given selector.  [See here.](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest#expr)

Comment: Yeah it's kinda handy :) Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to hear alot about the way this is structured in general. If you eliminate the table, a lot of this problem goes away.

Something like:

```
<div class="imgAndContent">
  <img src="blah.jpg">
  <span class="someDescription">Description.</span> <!-- or div, you choose based on your need -->
</div>
```

Then you can simply do...

```
var descriptionContent = $(this).next();
```

When the user clicks...

Comment: The table is valid, it's tabular data.

Comment: Well, I suppose two columns of data is still a table. Not quite black and white, but I hear you.